# How to know CPUxx is which socket?

Tags: cpu, utilities

I have two sockets (CPU), How to know CPU41 as below belongs to which CPU/socket?

```
hostname kernel: CPU41: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 438285593)
```

Comment: you could check with `cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep -E "(processor|physical|core id)" |less `

Comment: physical id is the socket number?

Comment: All I can say that I assume so - at least on my server it fits with the number of sockets in the server

Comment: you could also check `cat  /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu47/topology/physical_package_id`but that gives me on my server the same. I guess if that numbering follows the same rule as the markings on the mainboard probably depends on the manufacturer. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-devices-system-cpu states `physical_package_id: physical package id of cpuX. Typically corresponds to a physical socket number, but the actual value is architecture and platform dependent.`